# How can I create a table with ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree engine on clickhouse?

Tags: database, olap, clickhouse

I've been used clickhouse for a while, but it really confused me a lot.

So the problem is, when I'm trying to create a table with ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree engine, I set the engine as `ENGINE = ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/tableName/{shard}/', '{replica}')`, which included the param for ReplicatedMergeTree, but I don't know how to set the param for ReplacingMergeTree part.

I found no answer on documentations, which is sucks.

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table test (D Date, ID Int64, Ver UInt64)
ENGINE = ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/tableName/{shard}/',
 '{replica}', Ver)
partition by toYYYYMM(D)
order by ID
```

Comment: you're such a genius